# How to create an AI in Cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, artificial-intelligence

I am making a game (obviously) and to make it a remotely good one i need to have an AI. The problem is, where do I begin? I haven't done anything like this, and any help is appreciated. Links, other posts, tutorials, anything will suffice. Also note that I would like to have more than one enemy on the screen at once, so each of them will need an AI. Like I said, any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you could tell us what kind of game you're making? How the enemies will behave? That will give us a better idea of how to help. Also, have you come up with any ideas?

Comment: agree.. cause AI this topic is very broad.. It depends on what type of AI that you require, then we can help you..

Comment: @li.davidm @xuanweng i currently want the enemy to move around the screen and shoot at the character. i would like them to stop and shoot and then move again. Nothing too complicated. and once i get the basic AI thing down then I will just optimize it to fit needs in the future development of my app

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**first**: AI don't need/use Cocos2D classes

you need to build AI specific classes that controls your game objects/sprites etc...

**second**: this [link](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/reference/programming/artificial-intelligence/gaming/a-practical-guide-to-building-a-complete-game-ai-volume-i-r784) covers some basics of game AI

and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412720/how-to-make-a-basic-finite-state-machine-in-objective-c) explains how to make a finite state machine (FSM) in Objective C

a FSM is the most simple technique to build an AI in a game

Comment: +1 for AI don't need coco2d. Yeah AI is Artificial that means we have to implement it so it doesn't need cocos2d but your programming skills.

Answer (score 0):

Finite State Machine is the most common technique used for AI on mobile devices.
You also need to consider how much complex processing target device can handle without hampering user experience.

There's a good book for cocos2d: "Learning Cocos2D: A Hands-On Guide to Building iOS Games with Cocos2D, Box2D, and Chipmunk". You should check that out if it's your first game with cocos2d.