# Tracking progress within multiple threads

Tags: objective-c, ios5, architecture

I'm sure like most iOS apps, we have a networking operation that fetches data, one op that parses the data and a CoreData op that stores it and some UI events that display it... each op in it's own thread.

I am trying to figure out a clean approach to track the progress for each full cycle/task, right now I am basically creating a collection of unique ids for each defined cycle which are passed through each thread, it's status is updated when a Notification is sent on success/failure that I listen to, this seems messy.

Is there some type of framework that supports this?

Maybe a design pattern?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is something like a  [Finite-state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine).

[How to Make a Basic Finite State Machine in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412720/how-to-make-a-basic-finite-state-machine-in-objective-c)

Comment: I see where you were heading with this, I created something similar. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.